# Transition propriety on Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, cross-browser, transition

I am trying to make a div blur and unblur on checkbox change with a simple linear transition, and I managed to do that on Chrome. I now want to make it work either on Firefox, IE and Safari but I can't figure out how to do that.

The code I'm using is:

Div that will be blurred:

```
<div class="foo" style="transition-property: all;transition-duration: 350ms;transition-timing-function: linear;">
...
</div>
```

Checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Check Me" class="check"> Check me
```

JavaScript function:

```
function blurElement(element, size) {
    var filterVal = 'blur('+size+'px)';
    $(element)
        .css('filter',filterVal)
        .css('webkitFilter',filterVal)
        .css('mozFilter',filterVal)
        .css('oFilter',filterVal)
        .css('msFilter',filterVal);
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.check').change(function () {
        if ($('.check').prop("checked")) {
            blurElement(".foo",3);
        }
        else {
            blurElement(".foo",0);
        }
    });
});
```

Any ideas? This is working fine on Chrome, but no signs of life in other browsers :(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox does not support the `filter` property yet. It's getting close to being implemented thought, and we should hopefully see support in a few months. [Bug 869828](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=869828) tracks the last needed steps.

Until then, you can use [SVG filters](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-filters), preferably embedded in Data-URI format in your CSS. The `filter` property is by the way just a shorthand method to the more featureful SVG filters.